# How to keep direction of sprites?

Tags: python, random, pygame, simulation

Im trying to make a simulation.

My rabbit's are supposed to be moving around randomly, but i would like them to keep moving the same direction for longer, hence, why i use the `if randomnum == 1`, to only change the direction 1/10 times.

But when i run the code the rabbits seem to change direction every move. What am i doing wrong?

#### rabbit-constructor

```py
class Rabbit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10,10])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.xchange = 0
        self.ychange = 0
        self.hp = 100
```

#### rabbit-mover

```py
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        randomnum = random.randint(1,10)
        if randomnum == 1:
            xdir = random.randint(-5,5)
            ydir = random.randint(-5,5)
            rabbit.xchange = xdir
            rabbit.ychange = ydir
        else:
            continue
        if rabbit.rect.x+xdir > 10 and rabbit.rect.x+xdir < 390 and rabbit.rect.y+ydir > 10 and rabbit.rect.y+ydir < 390:
                rabbit.rect.x += rabbit.xchange
                rabbit.rect.y += rabbit.ychange
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `continue`. They skip the rest of the loop body and that is not needed here:

- in the first `if` whenever the rabbit's direction does not change, it will not move either, `continue` skips the second `if` and proceeds to the next rabbit
- in the second `if`, continue just makes the loop proceed to the next rabbit, which it would do anyway

Fix: remove them.

```
for rabbit in rabbits:
    randomnum = random.randint(1,10)
    if randomnum == 1:
        xdir = random.randint(-5,5)
        ydir = random.randint(-5,5)
        rabbit.xchange = xdir
        rabbit.ychange = ydir
    if rabbit.rect.x+xdir > 10 and rabbit.rect.x+xdir < 390 and rabbit.rect.y+ydir > 10 and rabbit.rect.y+ydir < 390:
        rabbit.rect.x += rabbit.xchange
        rabbit.rect.y += rabbit.ychange
```

Remarks:

- rabbits may stick to the border of the field for longer time, if that seems strange, you can extend the randomizer part with checking if the rabbit is at a border, and generate direction between -5...0 or 0...5 only
- updating the two positions may be separated into two `if`-s: just because a rabbit reaches the left side of the screen, it does not have to stop moving completely (the y coordinate could be still updated).